# ApplicationList size is 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stormpath

I am trying to get facebook data using [stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and spring boot. But I am getting ApplicationList size is 0.

```
        ApiKey apiKey = ApiKeys.builder().setFileLocation(path).build();
        Client client = Clients.builder().setApiKey(apiKey).build();
        Tenant tenant = client.getCurrentTenant();
        ApplicationList applications = tenant.getApplications(
                Applications.where(Applications.name().eqIgnoreCase("My Main"))
        ); // applications size is 0 I am getting

      Application application =  applications.iterator().next();
```

Any idea why is that?And how to get the application?

**Edit**: Here is my pom.xml

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stormpath.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>stormpath-sdk-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.RC4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stormpath.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>stormpath-sdk-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.RC4.4</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hi @Soham, I'm a Software Engineer at Stormpath and will be very happy to help you to resolve this issue, first thing, the name "My Main" for you application is an application you created via the Rest API or through the Admin Console?, asking to ensure that the application exists and we can take it from there.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?  1.0.RC4.5 is the latest and should correctly report sizes.

Comment: @jbarrueta thanks for your pinpoint.I gave the wrong application name,that's why  it's size is 0.Now it's working.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Soham glad to help, and don't hesitate to reach to us if needed.

Comment: @Soham as Les mentioned we recommend you to try the latest version of the SDK (i.e. 1.0.RC4.5) which has a bug and a new feature in it.

Comment: @jbarrueta .Ok I will do that.Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually It's my fault I have put the wrong application name  `"My Main"` .That's why I was getting the size 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationList applications = tenant.getApplications(
                Applications.where(Applications.name().eqIgnoreCase("My Main"))
        ); // applications size is 0 I am getting
```

Can you verify that your `Applications.name()` is correct ? It is stupid, but I think it cames from here :-)

You can also take a look to the simple [quickstart Stormpath tuto](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/quickstart/).

Comment: @Soham Could you actually right an answer then and accept that? That shows the community that it is actually solved and is better than adding (Solved) in the title.

Comment: @Timo I have answered my own question,what you have asked for.Thanks :)

Comment: So can you accept my answer as resolving your problem ? :-)

Comment: @Soham Can you also mark it as the answer? The time limit should have passed by now.